# Looking up positivity or negativity in a sentence using WordNet

Tags: c#, nlp, wordnet, sentiment-analysis

I have to ask some questions in an interactive system and user is free to type just anything as response. I have to conclude from response whether it is positive (yes) or negative (no). In some presentation that I attended few months ago I understood that a specific library of wordnet (not wordnet itself) exists that does the exact same job but I have forgot what it was. Does anyone know about it? If not can you suggest some alternative to attain the same result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind I recalled it now. It was [SentiWordnet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/).

Answer (score 0):

WordNet provides a C API with the main package downloads at http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/#comp0000498c0be300000059ff0e74

A reference for this API can be found at http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wnintro.3WN.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am aware of wordnet and utilizing it already. I am looking for another library derived from wordnet that finds out only positivity or negativity in a sentence.